# Gnome shell online accounts fails connection

Tags: gnome, gmail, online-accounts

i'm using ubuntu 12.04 (gnome shell) and i just setup the "online accounts" with my gmail. problem is, everytime i reboot my computer, it popups " connection to blablabla@gmail.com has failed".

A friend of mine talked to me in google chat and i got notified, so i guess the only part "broken" is the email. Anything i can do to fix it? would be very nice to receive mail notification there. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: go to Network settings and turn your proxy settings to none.

Comment: This answer needs some more information to be useful, such as instructions and screenshots.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue and do not have my proxy set to none.